# Difference Between Degrees on a circle

Tags: circles

What kind of math would I use to calculate the difference between two degrees on a circle? Say, 38 and 272 degrees?  When I just subtract one position from another sometimes it's more than 180 or sometimes I cross over 0/360.  I need keywords that can help me learn more about it.  Ultimately I want to create an excel formula but I don't know what it is called. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) operation?

Comment: yes may be modulo $2\pi$?

Comment: @Seyhmus or $\bmod 360$, if you want to keep things entirely in degrees.

Comment: @J.M. sure it seems more interesting)

Answer (score 9):

If $a$ and $b$ are angles in a circle, measured in degrees, with $0\le a\le b\lt360$, then the difference between them is the smaller of $b-a$ and $360+a-b$.

Answer (score 1):

Points on a circle whom angles differ only by a $2k\pi$ (where $k$ can be any positive or negative integer) are the same. So $25$ and $25+360=385$ and $25-360=-335$ are in the same position on the circle. It is said that $25$, $385$ and $-335$ are **congruent modulo $360$**  e.g. 
$$ 25 \equiv 385 \mod 360 $$
There is a convention which considers counter-clockwise rotation to add a positive angle to the starting angle and clockwise ones to add a negative angle to the starting angle.
Note: $\pi$ radians is equal to $180$ degrees
These are usually discussed in **Elementary Geometry** or **Elementary Trigonometry**
See these pages for further details:
[Trigonometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry)
[Euclidean geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_geometry)
[Circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle)

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh, fixed it. ;)

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Is it mathematically correct of saying that $\pi$ is **equal to** $180$ in degrees?

Comment: @Res, sorry, I must have missed your question. It is correct to say that $\pi$ radians equals 180 degrees. If context makes it clear that you are talking about radians, then it is correct to say that $\pi$ equals 180 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

The following aspect has not be addressed in the answers so far: One has to distinguish between oriented and nonoriented angles.

The *nonoriented angle* $\phi$ between two points ${\bf u}$, ${\bf v}\in S^1$ (the unit circle) is the length of the shorter arc on $S^1$ connecting  ${\bf u}$ and ${\bf v}$. It is a number between $0$ and $\pi$ (inclusive) and is given by the formula $\phi=\arccos({\bf u}\cdot{\bf v})$, where the $\cdot$ denotes the scalar product in ${\mathbb R}^2$. In terms of everyday geometry it is the angle  between the "rays" ${\bf u}$ and ${\bf v}$ as measured in degrees by a protractor.

The *oriented angle* is a notion connected to rotations and can be any real number; but depending on the problem at hand it may be restricted, e.g., to the interval $\ ]{-\pi},\, \pi[\ $. Let ${\bf u}_0=(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)\in S^1$ and a $\phi\geq0$ be given. Then the motion
$$t\mapsto {\bf u}(t):=\bigl(\cos(\alpha+t),\sin(\alpha+t)\bigl)\qquad(0\leq t\leq\phi)$$
turns ${\bf u}_0$ continuously counterclockwise  to a final position ${\bf u}(\phi)$. The total turning angle is $\phi$. A similar definition for $\phi\leq0$ produces a clockwise rotation. The final position ${\bf u}(\phi)$ coincides with the starting position ${\bf u}_0$ iff $\phi$ is an integer multiple of $2\pi$.

When dealing with geometrical (or kinematic) problems where angles are at stake one always should assert whether the introduced variables denote nonoriented or oriented angles.